# Is it true that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy}{x+y}=0$?

Tags: calculus

Is it true that
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\quad \frac{xy}{x+y}=0 ?$$
It seems to be true since if we choose that path $x=|t|^a$ and $y=|t|^b$ where $0<a<b$, when $t\to0$, then we obtain
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{|t|^{a+b}}{|t|^a+|t|^b}=
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{|t|^b}{1+|t|^{b-a}}=0.
$$
It it true for any path?

Comment: Doesn't this choice of variables imply that x,y > 0?

Comment: I took only one family of paths...do we get something else if we took a path that is not all positive?

Comment: Actually nevermind, your idea will work, just needs to be done in 4 separate scenarios, but with similar steps.

Comment: boaz, please, unaccept my answer so that I could delete it. I am sorry there seems to be a mistake. Thanks to @HansLundmark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try simply [plotting the graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x+y%2F%28x%2By%29)?

It's definitely **not** true that the limit is zero, since along the path $(x,y)=(t,-t+t^2)$ you have
$$
\frac{xy}{x+y} = \frac{t \, (-t+t^2)}{t^2} = -1 + t \to -1
,\qquad
t \to 0
.
$$
And if you want to make things even worse, along the path $(x,y)=(t,-t+t^3)$ you have
$$
\frac{xy}{x+y} = \frac{t \, (-t+t^3)}{t^3} = \frac{-1+t^2}{t} \to \mp \infty
,\qquad
t \to 0^{\pm}
.
$$

Comment: Thanks, I will delete my answer as soon as gets unaccepted. (+1)

Comment: Nice answer,  and definitely is the right one, but wolpham Alpha gives 0....do you know why is that,  please?

Comment: @dmtri: Exactly what input did you give to WA?

Comment: limit xy/(x+y) as (x,y)->(0,0), @Hans Lundmark

Comment: @dmtri: It might be computing $\lim_{x \to 0} \lim_{y \to 0}$ or something, I don't know... But it's a bit strange, since Mathematica correctly answers **Indeterminate** when given **Limit[x y/(x + y), {x, y} -> {0, 0}]** or **Limit[x y/(x + y), {x, y} -> {0, 0}, Direction -> Reals]**.

Answer (score 3):

The path $x=0$ and any $y\to 0$ ($y \ne 0$) gives the limit $0$. However, the path $x=u$ and $y = u^a - u$ gives a different result for any $a>2$.

Comment: This is neat! Never thought of applying AM-GM here.

Comment: This is not correct. The AM-GM estimate is $|xy| \le (x^2+y^2)/2$, not $|xy| \le |x+y|^2/2$.